# Not able to add devices to provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Running into an interesting issue here. My Xcode is refusing to build because my device doesn't show up in my distribution provisioning profile.

However, in member center, I can't seem to be able to choose my devices. I have 7 total iPhone devices registered. But when I click to my distribution provisioning profile, I see the following:

[image]

From what I gather, there should be a list of devices that appears, but nothing is there. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Devices only appear for development profiles, not distribution profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That totally got me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a "Development" profile.  Distribution profiles are for final distribution and don't link to specific devices.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is trying to do a distribution build.

Comment: Gah, yes, makes sense. I was trying to do a distribution build and put it on my phone to make sure it was working. Am now realizing that is not supposed to work. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Only type iOS App Development and Ad Hoc have devices list.

[image: Add iOS Provisioning Profiles]

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification!